# PHP SFTP with proxy

Tags: php, proxy, sftp, phpseclib

I'm searching for a class / extension / whatever that allows me to use a proxy for an SFTP connection in PHP.

I've checked the [ssh2_ftp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php) function and [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), but I didn't find any reference to proxy settings...

Any idea?

Comment: I have the same problem. @napolux did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

Would you be tunneling over SOCK4 or SOCK5 or HTTP CONNECT? Or something else?

One thing you might be able to do is modify phpseclib. eg. in the Net_SSH2 constructor, add in the code to connect to the proxy via SOCK4/5/whatever and then just let Net_SSH2 behave normally after that.

Comment: I was considering changing the library itself, but before doing that I'm searching for a "ready-made" solution. Thanks anyway. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have had no problem with using https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib and would recommend this method.  It also requires no installation on the server and is very easy to achieve most SFTP actions required.

Comment: In case anyone is new to this (like myself), [this is phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib).